# CXF xml config doesnt validate using disableCNcheck="true"

Tags: java, xml, cxf

I'm using a CXF config file copied directly from the CXF website at:
cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

However when I run my program the XML does not validate. The error given is:
Attribute 'disableCNcheck' is not allowed to appear in element 'http-conf:tlsClientParameters'

We are using self-signed certificates in a test environment and just need a quick workaround to use the services!

Here is the cxf.xml file I am trying to use, any help is appreciated!

```
<http-conf:conduit
    name="{https://hostname/service}MyService.http-conduit">
    <!--  deactivate HTTPS url hostname verification (localhost, etc)
    WARNING ! disableCNcheck=true should NOT be used in production-->
    <http-conf:tlsClientParameters  disableCNcheck="true" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute should be disableCNCheck  (capital C on Check).   I believe just fixing that should fix the issue.

Comment: That typo fixes the validation, however, the same exception is thrown as when the tag is missing: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate. To disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.

Comment: That's likely due to the "name" on the http-conf:conduit.  Two things to try.  1) {https://hostname/service}MyServicePort.http-conduit    as it should be the PORT name in the service, not the service name. or 2)  name="http://www.blah.com/.*" to regex on the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I switched the conduit name to  *.http-conduit" and at least it connects now!  I owe you a beer, Cheers!